# Reloading UITableView on Main Thread does not always work

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, swift, uitableview

I have the problem that when I reload the data of a UITableView on the main queue it doesn't reload the data all of the time. It only reloads the data roughly around 3 out of 5 times when I launch the app with some streaks of reloading (3 to 5 launches) and then some streaks of not-reloading (2 to 3 launches).

I'm testing this app on an iPhone 6 with iOS 8.4 and Xcode 7 Beta 4 using Swift 2.

This is the code for my UIViewController holding the UITableView, which is also the initial screen for the app after launching.

```
import UIKit

class TableController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let rowTitles = ["Date", "Temp", "Humidity", "Wind"]
    var tableData = [String : String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.setupLocationManager()
    }

    func setupLocationManager() {

        // Setting up a location manager 

        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        LocationData.ownLocation = locations.last!
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        self.setupTable()
    }

    func setupTable() {
        ApiClient.getCurrentWeatherAndSunData(LocationData.ownLocation) { (data, error) -> Void in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Could not get current weather and sun data")
                return
            }

            WeatherData.main = data!.valueForKey("main") as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            WeatherData.wind = data!.valueForKey("wind") as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

            self.setWeatherData()

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.ownTableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }

    func setWeatherData() {
        let temp = String(WeatherData.main["temp"] as! Int)
        let humidity = String(WeatherData.main["humidity"] as! Int)
        let windSpeed = String(WeatherData.wind["speed"] as! Int)

        self.tableData["Date"] = getDateStringWithFormat(NSDate(), formatString: "dd.MM.yyyy")
        self.tableData["Temp"] = "\(temp)°"
        self.tableData["Humidity"] = "\(humidity)%"
        self.tableData["Wind"] = "\(windSpeed) km/h"
    }
}

extension TableController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.rowTitles.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myReuseIdentifier = "ReuseIdentifierPrayerTimes"
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(myReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value2, reuseIdentifier: myReuseIdentifier)
            cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name: cell.textLabel!.font.fontName, size: 17.0)
            cell.detailTextLabel!.font = UIFont(name: cell.detailTextLabel!.font.fontName, size: 17.0)
        }

        let rowTitle = self.rowTitles[indexPath.row]
        let rowData = self.tableData[rowTitle]

        cell!.textLabel!.text = rowTitle
        cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = rowData

        return cell
    }
}
```

The problem is that even though the reloadData() function is called on the main thread and it is called after setting the values for the table in setWeatherData(), the table on my iPhone doesn't show the data.

The table does indeed show the data if I do this and go to another tab and come back:

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.ownTableView.reloadData()
}
```

My question is whether you can find the cause for this random behavior. I had the assumption that the reloadData() call comes too quickly after the initial loading of the table and therefore is disregarded. How do you organize an API call with subsequent data reloading of an UITableView after app launch?

Comment: You don't call `super.viewDidLoad()` or `super.viewDidAppear()` so good chance things are not setup right! Also where do you initialize your data model? Perhaps you initialize it after the data has arrived so reset it. What are you returning as the number of sections and number of rows when it fails from the delegate?

Comment: That didn't solve the problem, but thanks for the remark. I already wondered whether those calls are actually necessary as Xcode never complained about their absence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was that I added a prototype UITableViewCell to my UITableView in the Interface Builder (IB) of Xcode 7 Beta 4. I don't know why, but adding a prototype UITableViewCell to a UITableView in the IB caused problems in all the UITableViews. After deleting the prototype UITableViewCells again from the UITableViews in my project in IB everything works just fine. This way my code creates a couple of UITableViewCells upon launch and reuses them if I change their data and call reloadData() on the UITableView.

Comment: That's interesting. Could you perhaps show the UITableView delegate methods just to see? And did you use the correct cell identifier?

Comment: I've added the methods of the delegate and data source to the initial post. I copy pasted the exact identifier from the UITableViewCell in the IB to my code, so I guess there couldn't have lied the problem.

Comment: You shoudld really use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` rather than the version you are using. It will also never return nil unless your reuse identifier is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp, but I've tried it with the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` method and the same error stills occurs. If I add a UITableViewCell to my UITableView in the IB it causes problems. If I delete it no problems occur.

Comment: Did you have multiple prototype cells in one tableview?

Comment: Nope, only one. Once I dragged it in from the object library and once I simply set the value of **Prototype Cells* of the UITableView to 1. In both cases I got my bug. However, it still works nicely without the UITableViewCell.

Comment: It is unlikely to be xcode given how common an operation this is. Does the code actually go into cellForRowAtIndexPath when it seems not to work? If so what does `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentfier` return? I take it you are also coding with size class Any/Any view in IB and not in a size class view which would not exist in your test device? It must either be your cell not setup right, or more likely your data model has nothing in it when reload happens because it has nothing or your cleared it somewhere.

Comment: So, I've tested this now in Xcode 6.4 to make sure it isn't a bug of Xcode 7 Beta 4. The `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns the prototype cell as expected. I then update it's `detailTextLabel` and return the cell. However, although the cell has a text set for `detailTextLabel` it doesn't actually show on my phone or in the simulator. Yes, I use the size class Any/Any. I will set up a test project and try to recreate the problem. If I succeed I will create a radar and inform you about Apple's answer.

Comment: @PeterU And did you make sure you set the prototype cell type style to be something other than UITableViewCellStyleDefault. If set to the default it will not show `detailTextLabel`.